# Create Elliptical Curve Signing Key using TSS/C++

Tags: c++, security, sign

I need to create an elliptical signing key using the TSS/C++ library.
However when I create it I get a strange error from the TPM simulator:
TPM Error - TPM_RC::: The specified path is invalid.

Here is the method I use to create the signing key. Can someone show me what I am doing incorrectly

```
DWORD CreateKeyPair(Tpm2 tpm)
{
    DWORD retCode = 0;

    try
    {
        //Create a dummy PIN for now
        ByteVec userAuth = ByteVec{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        TPMS_SENSITIVE_CREATE sensCreate(userAuth, vector<BYTE>());

        vector<TPMS_PCR_SELECTION> pcrSelectSigning{};


        //signing key
        TPMS_ECC_PARMS signingKeyParams(TPMT_SYM_DEF_OBJECT(), 
            TPMS_SCHEME_ECDSA(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256), 
            TPM_ECC_CURVE::NIST_P256, 
            TPMS_NULL_KDF_SCHEME());

        //Signing key public template   
        TPMT_PUBLIC signingKeyTemplate(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256,
            TPMA_OBJECT::sign |                        // Key attribues
            // Not needed, TPMA_OBJECT::encrypt |
            TPMA_OBJECT::fixedParent |
            TPMA_OBJECT::fixedTPM |
            TPMA_OBJECT::sensitiveDataOrigin |
            TPMA_OBJECT::userWithAuth, 
            vector<BYTE>(),
            signingKeyParams,
            TPMS_ECC_POINT()
        );

        CreatePrimaryResponse singingPrimary = tpm.CreatePrimary(TPM_RH::OWNER, 
            sensCreate, 
            signingKeyTemplate, 
            vector<BYTE>(), 
            pcrSelectSigning);
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cout << "Exception thrown: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return retCode;
}
```

Comment: Nit:  It's "an elliptic curve signing key", not "an elliptical signing key".  More seriously, where does the error come from? and why are you asking for a key which can both sign and encrypt?

Comment: The error is coming from the TSS code. If I remove the "encrypt" (which you are right I do not need), then I get the following error message from the TPM: "TPM_RC::SYMMETRIC: System trace information was not specified in your CONFIG.SYS file, or tracing is disallowed."